# PHP 5.2 and 5.3 together

Tags: php, xampp

I have XAMPP with PHP 5.2, but my new projects need  PHP 5.3
How to have PHP 5.2 and 5.3 together?

I have winXP.

Comment: Closing to move to server fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

- **Ensure your older apps can run on 5.3 while not using 5.3 specific features.** This is probably the
     best route as it will tighten your
     code and it will run on more
     platforms, especially in the future
     when more production environments
     use 5.3 only.

  If this is for development purposes only you can also consider:
- **multiple installations
         of XAMPP** and switch between them
         when necessary via simple folder
         rename (somewhat tedious)
- **php-switch** (very tedious)
- **setup two apache servers** on the same machine **running different PHP versions**

Comment: "Multiple installations of XAMPP" is quite simple, in my opinion.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14896801/368896

Answer (score 1):

You've two choices: run two servers on a different port, or use CGI.

You can get XAMPP with PHP 5.3.1 here: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641
Edit `\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`, and change `Listen` to `Listen 8080` for example.
Then run `\xampp\apache_start.bat` to start that server instance. Optionally, change `DocumentRoot` to your project directory.

Comment: CGI is what my HSP uses to let us choose between 5.4, 5.3, 5.2 and 4 :)