# Trouble in MySQL After Downgrading PHP 5.3.8 to 5.2.17 on XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I was trying the answer given here > [Using XAMPP, how do i swap out PHP 5.3 for PHP 5.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302168/using-xampp-how-do-i-swap-out-php-5-3-for-php-5-2) Was gonna comment there, but apparently the commentbox is closed.

So I open  a new question. I was succesful to the part of running http://localhost. But when I open phpmyadmin or my web applcation, it shows as if my mySQL is not running.

While in fact, it is currently running. I can't run a new mysql bat too.

So what is the problem? Was going to coonsider WampServer but it would be a bit of mess to transfer the database again..

Comment: What happens when you try to run mysql.exe?

Comment: Hmm... okay, it is fixed now. Perhaps it is just me and my stupidity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by running stop_mysql.bat twice, then run the new start_mysql.bat. I'm not sure why but this solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I found something elsewhere on the web indicating the need to put libmysql.dll (from the php install dir) into the bin directory of my apache install (in my case, c:\xampp\apache\bin). This sorted it out for me.

This may have been because I downgraded php using a zipped version of 5.2.17, and an installer would have worked in some other case (though not this one due to differences between the xampp installer and the php MSI installer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Should be noted for future references in case something weird happen again.