# Moving Wordpress site from Linux to Windows throws errors

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I've been asked to move someone's blog from a Linux server to a Windows 2008 box. I used Xampp on the new box. When I try to access the blog I get the following errors:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-settings.php on line 472

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-settings.php on line 487

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-settings.php on line 494

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-settings.php on line 530

Strict Standards: Declaration of Walker_Page::start_lvl() should be compatible with Walker::start_lvl(&$output) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\classes.php on line 594

Strict Standards: Declaration of Walker_Page::end_lvl() should be compatible with Walker::end_lvl(&$output) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\classes.php on line 594

Strict Standards: Declaration of Walker_Page::start_el() should be compatible with Walker::start_el(&$output) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\classes.php on line 594

Strict Standards: Declaration of Walker_Page::end_el() should be compatible with Walker::end_el(&$output) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\classes.php on line 594

Strict Standards: Declaration of Walker_PageDropdown::start_el() should be compatible with Walker::start_el(&$output) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\classes.php on line 611

Strict Standards: Declaration of Walker_Category::start_lvl() should be compatible with Walker::start_lvl(&$output) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\classes.php on line 705

Strict Standards: Declaration of Walker_Category::end_lvl() should be compatible with Walker::end_lvl(&$output) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\classes.php on line 705

Strict Standards: Declaration of Walker_Category::start_el() should be compatible with Walker::start_el(&$output) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\classes.php on line 705

Strict Standards: Declaration of Walker_Category::end_el() should be compatible with Walker::end_el(&$output) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\classes.php on line 705

Strict Standards: Declaration of Walker_CategoryDropdown::start_el() should be compatible with Walker::start_el(&$output) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\classes.php on line 728

Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class wpdb in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 306

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\cache.php on line 103

Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class WP_Object_Cache in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\cache.php on line 425

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\query.php on line 21

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\theme.php on line 623

Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class WP_Dependencies in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\class.wp-dependencies.php on line 15

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\update.php on line 39

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\class.wp-dependencies.php:15) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newblogBlog\httpdocs\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 770
```

Any ideas?

Comment: They're _warnings_, not errors. They were probably there on the Linux box, but suppressed. In the short term, turn off warnings and it may all work. Your new PHP environment may be more recent, and so the warnings may cause more of an issue, so you may have to downgrade the version of PHP you're running (do this as a last resort however). Also, let the owner know, so they can get a PHP developer to fix them.

Comment: You apparently run a *very old* version of Wordpress and should consider upgrading it.

Comment: cool thanks halfer, although i cant see the html for the homepage of the wordpress blog, im browsing on localhost to the index.php file in httdocs. i presume this should be the homepage for the wordpress blog?

Answer (score 0):

I think your php.ini in your linux server was desactivating errors reporting.

For the strict standards you can hide them by removing `E_STRICT` from the option `error_reporting` in you php.ini file (but it may be better to fix them).

for the rest of the issues I do recommand you to fix them, especialy the warnings.

Also check that the PHP version in linux is the same as in windows, migrating from a version to another may result in issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

check the used php-version on the server and on the xammp-box. You can do this with creating a single file that contains the single line

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

This gives you the used versions. If you can use the same versions on old and new system you can get less warnings, perhaps...

And if there are still the warnings, you can filter them out with the right entries in the php.ini.

Comment: if the versions are different do i have the option to downgrade the version in xampp?

Comment: 5.1.6 old site - 5.4.4 new site

Comment: yes, you can find for sure an old version of PHP (Google will tell you where), or update Wordpress to an up-to-date-version that is compatible with the current PHP. If this site is just a private little system not accessible in public then the downgrading of the PHP is probably the faster solution.

Comment: [This link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302168/using-xampp-how-do-i-swap-out-php-5-3-for-php-5-2) shows you how to change the version. Now you just have to find the old version somewhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

it is recommended for a productive system to not display errors, someone could use the information to hack your system... you can change the detail level of displaying errors as mentioned by Yazmat, or turn off the [displaying of errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) in php.ini like this:

```
display_errors = 0
```