# Downgrade XAMPP PHP from 5.4 to 5.3 on Mac 10.7

Tags: php, xampp, osx-lion

I've got a Macbook Pro 13" 64bit (early '11) with the latest XAMPP version. This version is shipped with PHP 5.4.*.

As I'm developing sites for a server that runs Debian with php 5.3.* it's pretty confusing when uploading sites, testing them and to redo stuff because of different php versions.

So now I'm looking for a way to downgrade php from 5.4 to 5.3 - would be cool if there is a version-switcher, but not necessary for now.

stackoverflow had the question already by now, but it mostly states the fact of using Windows. The structure isn't the same, so I can't use the tips for my mac.

Here is an answer that I already tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422622
The problem is, that I can't start Apache after changing the file(s):

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 522 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 10 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/libphp5.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/libphp5.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
httpd: Syntax error on line 522 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 10 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/libphp5.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/libphp5.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

In an older version of XAMPP I found a phpswitcher-script and tried it with an older PHP version of XAMPP. The script tells me:

```
XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit compatibility library for your system.
```

Is there any way I can downgrade PHP?

Comment: If you are in the unfortunate situation where you can not upgrade ubuntu's PHP version you could brew php53: http://justinhileman.info/article/reinstalling-php-on-mac-os-x/ You might need to `brew tap homebrew/dupes` if you get an error about zlib

Comment: Well, in short: I downgraded XAMPP to 1.7.3...