# How do I change the default path of PHP in XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache, configuration, xampp, httpd.conf

I am using xampp for deploying web apps. It includes the PHP module in a package. Now what I want to do is change the default path to PHP so that I can make use of other versions of PHP without overwriting the existing module. My new copy of PHP exists on the desktop. How can I configure Apache to refer to the PHP module present on the desktop, rather than the default one?

Comment: I know your question asks about XAMPP, but Softaculous AMPPS has a built-in interface that allows you to switch between PHP versions. This question is possibly a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/123902/getting-xampp-to-work-with-multiple-version-of-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using XAMPP, how do i swap out PHP 5.3 for PHP 5.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302168/using-xampp-how-do-i-swap-out-php-5-3-for-php-5-2)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Download your desired version of the PHP thread-safe binary (zipped) from http://windows.php.net/download/.
2. Unzip the downloaded version of the PHP in a separate directory. Please make sure that your new php directory's name is not "PHP". (For example, use `php54` for PHP 5.4)
3. Copy the new PHP directory into your XAMPP directory. (**DO NOT** overwrite your existing `php` directory!)
4. Now go to your xampp/apache/conf/extra directory. Make a backup of, then open the `httpd-xampp.conf` file.
5. Change the following variables/directives:

   `PHPINIDir` to be `[your xampp folder]/[new version of PHP]`

   `LoadModule` to be `[your xampp folder]/[new version of PHP]/php5apache2_2.dll`
6. Save the `httpd-xampp.conf` file. Restart your XAMPP apache server. If your server gets restarted successfully, then your server's PHP version was upgraded. You can check the status of your PHP version by using the URL `[localhost][:port]/xampp/phpinfo.php`.

If you are still having issues, try this as well:

Change the `LoadFile "[xammp folder]/php/php5ts.dll"` directive to `LoadFile "[xampp folder]/php54/php5ts.dll"`

An alternative is to use WAMP Server (on Windows only), since it allows you to install and switch between multiple versions of Apache, MariaDB, MySQL and PHP (including running both MariaDB and MySQL on different ports).

Source : http://www.techflirt.com/how-to-upgrade-php-in-xampp/

Comment: I run xampp on solaris
there's no httpd-xampp.conf file nor PHPINIDir variable in any file

Comment: @Ben Hmm. Having never used Solaris, I wouldn't know about that. I assume there must be something similar (either `httpd.conf` or `xampp.conf`). AFAIK, Solaris is *NIX-based, so it should be possible to install and use a full LAMP stack (search for the appropriate components) through its package manager (`apt`, `yum`, `debi`, `dpkg`, or equivalent).