# Whoops, looks like something went wrong. Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel-5

I installed Laravel 5.0 properly by cloning in git, and composer install, when I ran it to browser `http://localhost/laravel/public/`, it says

> "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

I did not make any changes after composer install.

**Update** after copy the env.example to .env this is result

> RuntimeException in compiled.php line 5599: OpenSSL extension is required.

Comment: Have you checked any logs?  If it's giving you a message, it means the server is up, but something is wrong.  Post those details in the question, and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: @mjuarez  where to see the logs ?

Comment: Then you'll have to install the openssl extension.

Comment: @majidarif I give you points. can you post your answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: @jemz I don't even know what platform and server you're using. Please provide details. Windows? Apache? Ubuntu? NginX?

Comment: @majidarif, sorry if you mis understood my reply..I mean it works now,just installing the openssl,I want to post your answer so that i can accept it as answer. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't give you an answer. The guy @kylehyde215 did. His answer led you to find the actual issue and fix it. You should accept his answer. Good day.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The logs are located in `storage` directory. If you want laravel to display the error for you rather than the cryptic 'Whoops' message, copy the `.env.example` to `.env` and make sure `APP_ENV=local` is in there. It should then show you the detailed error messaging.

Comment: If it still doesn't work & you see the error about cipher, run "php artisan key:generate"

Comment: i am also facing the same issue

Comment: Try composer dump-autoload also.

Comment: before use ```php artisan key ...``` you must add ```APP_KEY=``` to ```.env``` file.

Answer (score 70):

This is happening because there is a field in `.env` file named, **APP_KEY**, which is blank now, we need some random key for this variable.

Follow these steps to get rid of this problem.

1. Rename `.env.example` to `.env`
2. Go to your root directory in your command prompt (If you are using   windows)/terminal (If you are using MAC or LINUX) where you have installed laravel   project/files and run following command

   `php artisan key:generate`

and then run your project.
It's all done.

Comment: Have been searching for an answer for so long. Got this problem when my team put the Laravel-project on GitHub. The Vendor-folder is ignored by GitHub and we have to reinstall Composer. The .env-folder is renamed to .env.example and no-one got a clue what went wrong. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: I had also found it very strange... and then I went through the documentation and found the solution....

Comment: guys, this is the answer

Answer (score 23):

- Give write permission to storage and bootstrap/cache directories
- Rename .env.example file to .env
- If you get "RuntimeException... No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid." error, stop the application and generate key from command line "php artisan key:generate"
- If your get "OpenSSL extension is required" error, enable the openssl extension by opening php.ini in php installation folder and uncommenting the line extension=php_openssl.dll by removing the semicolon at the beginning

Comment: fantastic solution. It helpful for me.

Comment: Simply the best answer for this question.

Answer (score 10):

Follow these steps to this problem for all versions of your laravel like `laravel 5.5`

Step: 1

Rename file `.env.example` to `.env`

Step: 2

Go to your Command prompt/terminal and change path to project directory.
Generate key for your application. This is unique for every application so don't make copy paste.

Just run the following command. Key will automatically save to your .env file

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 6):

**Try to type in cmd:**
php artisan key:generate
the problems will be solved

Comment: perfect solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply type in terminal in your command prompt go to laravel directory path and type `php artisan key:generate` then key will be generated. Paste that key in `config/app.php` key variable. Your problem will be solved. I also did like that `inorder` to solve the problem...

Answer (score 3):

Please, try to find something like:

```
./website/config/app.php and set 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false) as 'true' 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

> sudo chown -R www-data pathto/.env

**BECAUSE IF After Creating the .env file or/and Generating the Key by**

```
php artisan key:generate
```

just as explained previously by others, and it still persists
Try the following:

```
ls path/.env -al
```

if apache doesn't have access to it by displaying

> www-data

as one one of the users i mean like

> -rw-rwx--- 1 www-data rootuser 575 Nov  4 06:34 pathto/.env

This as stated above should resolve it. Especially when your laravel.log file keeps complaining that the key hasn't been generated or added.

> sudo chown -R www-data pathto/.env

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.5, I had the same issue

```
.env
```

was added to .gitignore.

So Either remove ".env" it from .gitignore file.

or add it forcefully

```
git add .env -f
```

And Deploy it. It will work.

If above does not help. Try generating the Key Again

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: this is not a best practice to remove the env from a gitignore file as it can contain sensitive informations...

Answer (score 1):

Check, which PHP version is running on your WAMP,XAMPP or LARAGAN server. It should be greater than 7.0.

1. Go to project folder like "C:\wamp\www\laravel".
2. Open the file name of `.env.example`. (By using any editor like sublime, notepad++ and so on).
3. Save as a `.env`

Then run your LARAVEL program. Hope it will work.

You can check whether how to change the PHP version in your current server. [xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022609/how-to-change-default-path-of-php-in-xampp), [wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237695/how-to-downgrade-wampserver-php-and-apache)

Answer (score 1):

I renamed the ***.env.example*** to ***.env*** and ensure

```
APP_ENV=local
```

which showed me the actual error. It was related to key.
Then I issued

```
php artisan key:generate
```

command  and it worked

Answer (score 1):

For windows users, make sure apache's ssl_module is checked.

Please see image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First run command `composer install`

Then check for .env.example and .env files in your project folder.

.env file is your main configuration file for database and .env.example is backup file for .env file.

.env.example file will always be there but sometimes .env file can be missing.
just copy the .env.example file and paste in the same project folder with filename .env .

now run `php artisan key:generate` command. this will generate key for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy these files from template "blog" laravel

[image]

Comment: I see 2 files with the same empty name, how can this be valid? Not even a link is provided to copy them files. My flag has been disputed, this needs a removal unless the OP updates, which is very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

make sure **app/storage** dir permission is set to 755 and owner is set to admin. and also check permission and owner of files and dir in **app/storage** too

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `.env` file and copy the code of `.env.example` and run the command -> `php artisan key:gen`

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename the **.env.example** to **.env**
2. Go to *bootstrap=>app.php* and uncomment `$app->withEloquent();`
3. Make sure that APP_DEBUG=true in .env file.
   Now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Go to the `.env` file and be sure `APP_DEBUG=true`
2. Here (in `.env` file) change `reemplace 127.0.0.1` for `localhost` for check if your DB credential are corrects.
3. Go to the `config` folder and do. the step #2.

Comment: Please review [how to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before your next post.. Grammar, Spelling, etc are *IMPORTANT*.  While I fixed most of the egregious grammatical errors, typos, and formatting, parts of this post are still unclear and need to be corrected.

Answer (score -1):

in process of uploading `env` file to cpanel,

sometimes the dot is taken out and this may raised the error.

this solution worked for me.

> go to your cpanel and **rename** `env` file to `.env`