# How to change global PATH php?

Tags: php, macos, path, xampp, macos-sierra

When I run Apache via XAMPP Web Server I see that PHP version is:
5.6.30 using command: `phpinfo();`

But when I do `php -v` in console I get another version.

How to change global PATH php from XAMPP?

XAMPP uses: `.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php`

Comment: [I think this might help. Just change the httpd-xampp.conf file to refer to the version of php that you want to use. ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23029961/4750964)

Comment: It is not full information, I just need to change PATH

Answer (score 0):

I hope this  will work for you

step1: `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`

Add the below content.

step2:

```
   export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP

   export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

   export PATH
```

Finally load your changes

step3: `source ~/.bash_profile`